# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When I start my SettingsActivity, I get the following Error, but I don't know why, because I have done everything as always.

ERROR:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                  Process: com.android.niklasvlach.vertretung, PID: 9175
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.niklasvlach.vertretung/com.android.niklasvlach.vertretung.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference                                                                                    at com.android.niklasvlach.vertretung.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:28)                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)`

The Code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner select;
EditText username;
EditText password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    select = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectclass);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_view);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_view);

    select.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long text) {
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"" + text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
}
```

}

If anything else is needed, I will post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your UI work after setting the layout of the Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    select = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectclass);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_view);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_view);

    select.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long text) {
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"" + text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```